# How can i keep deformed skinned mesh and rigged bones after scaling them?

Tags: mesh, rigging, scale

i rigged a mesh with bones, an Eagle model i'been making, and then i scaled the wings by scaling the bones, but now i want to keep the mesh like that (bigger wings) plus the scaled bones, but everything as if it were the main, basic position of it, how can i do that?
If i go to object mode, the model gets smaller, but i want to keep the present proportions in Pose mode as the base one.

Thanks in regard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pose your model as wanted, select your mesh, in the properties panel - object mode  - apply the armature modifier, select the armature in pose mode, select all bones, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
 "Apply pose as rest pose", then select the mesh and readd an armature modifier, choose your rig as "object".

Be aware that the new rig will not execute old animations properly.