# How do I flip an armature to face the other way?

Tags: modeling, armature, transforms

I have a model that i realized was facing the wrong way, so I rotated it 180 degrees to face the opposite direction, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the armature face that direction as well.

Im a 100% noob so pretend i know almost absolutely nothing if you want to help me please.

Comment: If you flip your mesh using the armature, you can follow theese instructions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94050/how-can-i-keep-deformed-skinned-mesh-and-rigged-bones-after-scaling-them/94083#94083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're in object mode. Then rotate the armature instead of the mesh. The mesh will rotate with the armature if you have it parented (and if it isn't, then the armature won't do you any good because it won't deform the mesh!). Then apply the rotation both on the armature and on the mesh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.

To make your armature deform the mesh, first select your mesh, then your armature and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>. Choosing "With automatic weights" from the resulting popup is a good first step.