# How to "straighten" a rigged character's head

Tags: mesh, rigging

So I have a playermodel that isn't in a t-pose, I managed to rig it with an autorigger, however the issue is that his head is turned slightly to the side around 20-30 degrees meaning he is stuck looking to the side when animated. Is there a way that I can use the bones to straighten out the character's head permanently so he looks forward?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94050/how-can-i-keep-deformed-skinned-mesh-and-rigged-bones-after-scaling-them/94083#94083

Answer (score 1):

You can try rotating the bone to be straight and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select rotation to apply the current rotation as default/rest position,